# Using CruiseControl.NET to deploy

Tags: deployment, cruisecontrol.net

I've been using CruiseControl.NET for continuous integration and such. Now I want to be able to deploy projects with it. What is the preferred way of doing this? Do I make a new project which I 'Force Build' to deploy?

I really don't want to deploy on every successful commit.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how we do it. We have a separate CC project that only builds when forced. All this project does is push out the latest code to all the production boxes. The actual work of deploying is done via a MSBuild script. Whenever we want to do a push, we just force a build on that deployment project.